# Subsonic - Get All Columns From Joined Tables

Tags: inner-join, subsonic2.2

How do I display columns from both tables with an "InnerJoin" from SubSonic?

```
var myQuery = New SubSonic.Select().From(TableObject1)
                          InnerJoin(TableObject2.ID,TableObject1.ID)
```